Upgrading aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper from 2.3.2 -> 2.3.4 failed license
I had need to upgrade version of one of my dependencies after doing it my the task of license report is not working due to this error:
Execution failed for task ':kotlin_lambdas:licenseReport'.

> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

After removing some dependencies and check all the plugins, I find out that the configuration for license report to create CSV file with this plugin is not working as expected and return that error.
id("com.jaredsburrows.license") version "0.9.3"

licenseReport {
    generateCsvReport = true
    generateHtmlReport = false
    generateJsonReport = false
    generateTextReport = false
    ignoredPatterns = setOf()

    // These options are ignored for Java projects
    copyCsvReportToAssets = false
    copyHtmlReportToAssets = false
    copyJsonReportToAssets = false
    copyTextReportToAssets = false
}

The dependency that was need upgrade was "software.amazon.jdbc:aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper" from version 2.3.2 to 2.3.4.
Any advice what can I do about it because I need the csv file for the CI/CD process
I tried to upgrade that library to different other versions and still got that error and also add this configuration
implementation("software.amazon.jdbc:aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper:2.3.2") {
        isTransitive = false
    }
implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:rds:2.21.22")
implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:sts:2.21.22")

which worked but when try it on my bitbucket-pipeline execution it make the pipeline failed due timeout and the time took to build the jar files increased from 5 min to 30 min
